# javascript passing event in closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I was trying the following:

```
f.addEventListener('submit',(function(frm){
var func = (function(e){somefunction(e,frm);})(e);
})(f),false);
```

But this is failing. I want to pass the form (f) as a static reference and the dynamic event object to the named function 'somefunction'.

What I have above isnt working, what is the right syntax for passing both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that each of the `function`s is being called right away, with `undefined` actually being passed to `addEventListener()`.

You'll want to instead `return` one of the `function`s without its calling parenthesis so the event can call it later:

```
f.addEventListener('submit', (function (frm) {
    return function (e) {
        someFunction(e, frm);
    };
})(f), false);
```

---

Though, with event bindings, you may not necessarily need the closure, as the `<form>` will be the context (`this`) of the `function` passed:

```
f.addEventListener('submit', someFunction, false);

function someFunction(e) {
    var frm = this;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not saure exactly what you are trying to do but, to looks like you are trying to manually pass in the form via the event handler. Instead save a reference and just refer to it in the handler such as

```
f.addEventListener('submit',function(){
    var func = function(e){
      somefunction(e,f);
    };
},false);
```

you shouldn't need the self executing functions unless I am missing your intent here

Comment: lol yea this was more of a see fi itll work type thing. there are definitely cleaner ways around it.

Comment: gotcha ;) fun with functions